# using Django Sqlite in windows

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to use sqlite for development in django, with these settings:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'D:\database.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

but when i try to do syncdb i get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
438, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191,
in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 220,
in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351,
in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
, line 56, in handle_noargs
cursor = connection.cursor()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 250,
in cursor
cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
207, in _cursor
self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Any idea what's going on?
Notice that I tried to change the db name (location) many times but it didn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

Use forward slashes or [`r''` strings](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) to begin with.

```
'default': {
    # [... snip ...]
    'NAME': 'D:/database.db',
    # (or...) 'NAME': r'D:\database.db',
    # [... snip ...]
}
```

Additionally you need to ensure the *entire directory* your Sqlite file is in is writable (in this case `D:/`), as Sqlite needs to write its journal file next to the database file.

Comment: tried that , it didn't work, i still get the same problem, i tried relative path also, and C:\Temp\database.db, but i still get the same error ..

Comment: Are you sure you're using an `r''` string and/or forward slashes? Failing those, you could try using procmon to see what the process is trying to do when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': 'c:/projects/blog/first.db',  
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using only the name of the database file (no path). By default, Django will place it in the same directory as manage.py

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'database.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```